# React Typescript: Two different States are Updating

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have two different States from the same class.

For some reason, both get updated through `this.setState({selectedRecord: newValue})`:

```
selectedRecord: ModelClass,
question: Array<ModelClass>,
```

The state `question` is used in a Table for rendering all data, and the state `selectedRecord` is a copy of the selected Row, which is used to modify the Row via an Form.

```
<Button type="primary" icon={<EditOutlined />} onClick={() => {
      this.setState({ selectedRecord: record }, () => {
      this.setState({ modalVisible: true });
   });
}} />
```

So in the Form I modify the state `selectedRecord` via Input, Checkbox... and complete it with an setState, but the problem is that the changes are also mutate the `question` State.

Comment: "_the state selectedRecord is a copy of the selected Row_": how do you make that "copy"?

Answer (score 0):

your `dropdownItems` has been mutated, try this to retrieve data from your dropdownItems `Temp.group = [...this.state.dropdownItems][index].group`

Answer (score 0):

When you do this:

```
let Temp = this.state.selectedRecord;
Temp.group = this.state.dropdownItems[index].group;
Temp.free = this.state.dropdownItems[index].free;
```

...you actually modify the properties (*mutate*) your *previously* selected record. Therefore you now make it look like your next selected one. And it affects your question state if it contains a reference to that previous record.

It is unclear why you seem to need to retrieve your previously selected record in the first place, rather than just setting the next one with e.g.:

```
// No need for Temp at all
this.setState({ selectedRecord: this.state.dropdownItems[index] });
```

Comment: The mutate of the selectedRecord is intentional. For a better understanding: I have a Table with all entries and if I press the Edit Button then I copy the selected record from the Table to the state selectedRecord. Thereon a From opens and all changes will mutate the selectedRecord. But now they also mutate the question state. They have no reference.
(The state dropdownItems is another model, thats the reason why I dissolve it.)

Comment: It seems from your above description that you should add much more details to your question, especially regarding the difference between your `question` and `dropdownItems` states.

Comment: There is probably a misunderstanding, the ```dropdownItems``` have nothing to do with the problem. I have edit the question for a better understanding of the problem.